# Why do we put the null terminator in brace enclosed char array initialization

Tags: c

I noticed that in many books and online tutorials when C strings are initialized using brace enclosed lists, it is done like this:

```
char string[100] = {'t', 'e', 's', 't', '\0' };
```

Shouldn't all unspecified values automatically be set to 0 (aka `'\0'`)?

I tested this on multiple versions of GCC and MSVC, all values are indeed set to zero, but I'm wondering if there's a specific reason for explicitly writing the null terminator when initializing.

Comment: I think old versions of the C standard didn't say that extra elements should be zeroed.

Comment: Hint: what happens when you write `char string[] = { 't', 'e', 's', 't' };`? Would this be good to pass to printf()?

Comment: @Jens That's different, because it doesn't specify the array size.

Comment: @Jens that's different, you didn't specify the array length.

Comment: @Barmar Exactly my point. It's defensive programming. You can switch from one to the other without ill effect.

Comment: @Barmar: C90 says (§6.5.7 Initialization): _If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are members of an aggregate,
the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static
storage duration._  (Aggregate means 'structure or array' in this context.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I mean really old, like K&R.

Comment: @Barmar: Since C90 largely standardized what K&R said happened (at least in the language), I'd be surprised to find that K&R 1st Edition didn't say the equivalent of what the C90 standard says (and even more surprised to find a compiler of that era that didn't implement what the standard says should happen).  However, my K&R1 is at home and I'm not, so I can't readily verify that just yet.  I doubt if it is critical to anyone except antiques like myself who worked with such ancient compilers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right (see "Initialization from brace-enclosed lists" [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization)). But it's a good practice because this would also compile without complaints:

```
char string[4] = {'t', 'e', 's', 't'};
```

but wouldn't null-terminate anything, which would lead to errors whenever you would use that as a string. If you say

```
char string[4] = {'t', 'e', 's', 't', '\0'};
```

the compiler will know it's an error because the `'\0'` won't fit.

Note that it's superior even to

```
char string[100] = "test";
```

for the same reason:

```
char string[4] = "test";
```

does the same as the first example, not the second!

Answer (score 2):

It's to prevent silly mistakes. The first null character is required if the characters are to be interpreted as a string.

```
char string[4] = {'t', 'e', 's', 't'};
```

will happily compile, but will not be null-terminated.

```
char string[4] = {'t', 'e', 's', 't', '\0'};
```

will fail to compile, which is the point.

By explicitly specifying the null character, the compiler will verify that the array is large enough for its intended purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Adding null terminator is absolutely unnecessary when you specify the size of your character array explicitly, and allocate more chars than is needed for the payload portion of your string. In this situation the standard requires that the remaining chars be initialized with zeros.

The only time when it is necessary is when you want the size of a null-terminated array to be determined automatically by the compiler, i.e.

```
char string[] = {'t', 'e', 's', 't', '\0' };
//         ^^
```